# Верстка в Opera и Chrome на Windows и Mac OS выглядит по-разному

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка, кроссбраузерность, кроссплатформенность

Название и свойства блоков:

Круг слева:

```
#left_b {margin-top: 65px;
        float: left;
        width: 175px;
        height: 240px;}
```

Проблемный блок - кнопка Заказать звонок и белый прямоугольник:

```
#middle_b {float: left;
           height: 305px;
           width: 445px;
           padding-left: 70px;
           margin-top: 0px;}
```

Круг справа:

```
#right_b {margin-top: 65px;
         margin-left: 104px;
         float: left;
         width: 175px;
         height: 240px;}
```

---

- На первом скрине - так верстка выглядит на браузерах Chrome и Opera на Windows (и так должно быть).
  Для Edge пришлось еще дописать:

  ```
   @supports (-ms-accelerator:true) {
     #midle_b { margin-top: -45px !important; } 
   }
  ```

  [image: Screen Windows]
- На втором скрине - так выглядит на браузерах Chrome и Opera в Mac OS (просит margin-top: 28px). Когда middle_b опускается на 28px, надпись с белым джойстиком тоже становится на место

[image: Screen Mac OS]

- На третьем скрине - на Safari

[image: Screen Safari]

Подскажите, как исправить

У зеленого блока с джойстиком такие свойства:

```
    position: relative;
    top: -19px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 29px
```

Comment: можно попробовать поменять margin на padding.

Comment: весь бы код видеть . Не ясна сама вёрстка , и не видно @media запросы - скрины здесь не помогут , сайт на удалёнке или на локалке ?

Comment: @LenovoID [ссылка на проблемную страничку](http://adrenalinegame.ru/terminal_prizes)

Answer (score 1):

Честно, мне кажется что надо бы полностью всю вёрстку сайта менять, бо куча косяков и даже то место где где две колонки с текстом, можно было бы завернуть в

```
<table></table>
```

куча падингов не понятных, а для телефона то он вообще смещен в разные стороны.